# Generating huge amount of hashes

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, hash

I want to generate a large amount (10 TB) of seemingly random, but predictable numbers. The generation speed should exceed that of fast SSDs, so I want 3000 MB/s to 4000 MB/s.

After the file has been written, the numbers will be read again and generated again, so that they can be compared. The total program is supposed to check disks.

At the moment I'm thinking of hashes. The data to be hashed is just a 8 byte number (`ulong`) for the predictability. So in the binary file it looks like this

```
<32 bytes of SHA256(0)> <32 bytes of SHA256(1)> ...
```

I don't think I can use a Random number generator with a seed, because I can't tell the random number generator to generate the *n*th number. But I can tell the SHA256 algorithm to calculate SHA256(n).

I made a test with 128 MB of data using the SHA256 algorithm like this:

```
Parallel.For(0, 128 * 1024 * 1024 / 32,     // 128 MB / length of the hash
    a => {
        var sha = SHA256.Create();
        sha.Initialize();
        var ba = new byte[8];
        ba[0] = (byte)((long)a >> 0 & 0xFF);
        ba[1] = (byte)((long)a >> 8 & 0xFF);
        ba[2] = (byte)((long)a >> 16 & 0xFF);
        ba[3] = (byte)((long)a >> 24 & 0xFF);
        ba[4] = (byte)((long)a >> 32 & 0xFF);
        ba[5] = (byte)((long)a >> 40 & 0xFF);
        ba[6] = (byte)((long)a >> 48 & 0xFF);
        ba[7] = (byte)((long)a >> 56 & 0xFF);
        var hash = sha.ComputeHash(ba);
        // TODO: aggregate the byte[]s, stream to file
    }
);
```

Like that, the throughput is only 95 MB/s on my Ryzen 7 2700X 8 core processor running at 4,08 GHz.

Any chance of speeding this up to 4000 MB/s?

Comment: *"seemingly random, but predictable"* -- What do you mean by that? What are the desirable properties of those numbers? How are you going to use them?

Comment: Does it have to be hashes, as opposed to any other pseudo-random numbers?

Comment: "Seemingly random, but predictable" - what's the motivation for this? You can use `Random` with a constant seed to generate numbers but you might as well just have a text file with 10TB of pre-created random numbers.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I've added the motivation to the question. It shall be a disk test program.

Comment: @harold: it could be any other pseudo random number. However, I need to be able to calculate the n-th number without calculating all other numbers before.

Comment: @asaf92: I've updated the question. I don't think Random with a seed works, because I need to be able to calculate the n-th number on its own.

Comment: How about storing the numbers as they are, unhashed? Would this make the disc-testing procedure less reliable?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: yes. Given I store 64 bit numbers (in order to reach 10TB disks and above) and I'm writing to a 4 GB SD card (32 bit), the upper half of the data would always be 0 and the program would not detect broken or shorted wires in that part of the data.

Comment: How about creating `long` numbers [from two `int`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827252/c-sharp-making-one-int64-from-two-int32s)? Or simply by using the same `int` twice? `long number = (long)i << 32 | (long)(uint)i;`

Comment: I'm no expert but as far as I understand, one of the features of a good hashing algorithm is to work relatively slow, because it's usage in cryptography, the slower it runs the harder is using it for brut force attacks. 
You really should consider a different way to generate your pseudo-random values.

Comment: Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385501/3094533) by Ani. It's simple, easy, and I think can give you almost exactly what you're looking for. (Instead of using just the index, you can use the index + your own seed if you want to)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: thanks for the suggestion. Random numbers with a seed is just generating numbers at ~150 MB/s,

Comment: FYI: in the meanwhile I have implemented XXH64 and optimized for small data (8 bytes). That gives me ~1600 MB/s to 2000 MB/s.

Comment: XXH64 @ 3200+ MB/s now.

Comment: Assuming that the quality of the hash is not a top priority, you might find some even faster hashing algorithms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664014/what-integer-hash-function-are-good-that-accepts-an-integer-hash-key "What integer hash function are good that accepts an integer hash key?") or [here](https://gist.github.com/badboy/6267743 "Integer Hash Function").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think is is possible to reach that speed without using a gpu.
But here are few things you can do to gain some performance:

1. You can utilize the localInit of `Parallel.For` to create the SHA256 object, as well as a byte array of size 8 to hold the data to be hashed, once per task.
2. There is no need to explicitly call `Initialize`.
3. Instead of converting the long to byte array manually, one byte at a time, you can use pointers or the `Unsafe` class to set the bytes all at once.
4. Pre-allocate the array of bytes that will hold the hash and use `TryComputeHash` instead of `ComputeHash` since it allows passing a span for the output.

Here is a code implementing the mentioned above:

```
Parallel.For(0, 128 * 1024 * 1024 / 32,     // 128 MB / length of the hash
  () => (SHA256.Create(), new byte[8], new byte[32]),
  (a, state, tuple) =>
  {
    Unsafe.As<byte, long>(ref tuple.Item2[0]) = a;
    tuple.Item1.TryComputeHash(tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3, out _);
    var hash = tuple.Item3;
    // TODO: aggregate the byte[]s, stream to file
    return tuple;
  },
  tuple => tuple.Item1.Dispose()
);
```

Comment: Cool. This speeds up to ~400 MB/s. Not enough for me yet, so I'll look into other options. I definitely learned something, thanks.

Comment: How are you measuring the speed? and How are you writing the file?

Comment: I am measuring the speed using a C# Stopwatch for the given code. I am not writing to a file (yet; for this speed test). It is limited by CPU and RAM only (Release Build).

Comment: One more improvement is to also pre-allocate the output array use `TryComputeHash` instead of `ComputeHash` since it uses spans. Check the edited answer.

Comment: It seems that leaves the capabilities of .NET Framework and I would need to switch to .NET Core.

Comment: You can use `Span<T>` in .NET Framework as well. Just use the NuGet package

Comment: Also, measure using BenchmarkDotNet, not `Stopwatch`